# Why does a React component's onClick event handler not fire when the "display" attribute of a sibling node is changed?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

We ran into an issue, not sure what we're doing wrong. We've recreated [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pyraz/y485c6oy/)

**The Issue**

We have 3 components, a parent Form component, which has 2 children, an Input and a Button. The Button has both `onMouseDown` and `onClick` handlers registered. The Input has an `onBlur` handler registered. If you focus the Input, then click the button, the Button's `onMouseDown` will fire, followed by the Input's `onBlur`. The `onBlur` triggers a re-rendering of the parent Form component, to update it's CSS class. This new class, of `error`, causes a `div` that is a sibling of of the Input and the Button to become visible, per the CSS rules in the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pyraz/y485c6oy/). It appears that the changing of this CSS rule is what causes the Button's `onClick` handler to never fire. If you try clicking the Button again, it works as expected.

Anyone have any ideas what might be going on here?

Here's the JS code:

```
    var state = {
    messages: []
}

var MessageCenter = React.createClass({
    messages: function () {
        return this.props.messages.map(function (message, i) {
            return <div key={i}> {message}</div>
        })
    },

    render: function () {
        return <div>
            <h3>Events</h3>
            <div>{this.messages()}</div>
        </div>
    }
})

ReactDOM.render(
    <MessageCenter messages={[]}/>,
    document.getElementById('messageCenter')
)

function printMessage(message) {
    state.messages.push(message)
    ReactDOM.render(
        <MessageCenter messages={ state.messages }/>,
        document.getElementById('messageCenter')
    )
}

var Button = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function (event) {
        this.props.handleClick(event)
    },

    handleMouseDown: function (event) {
        printMessage('Button Mouse Down handled')
    },

    render: function () {
        printMessage('Button Rendered')
        return <div>
            <button onClick={ this.handleClick } onMouseDown={ this.handleMouseDown }> Click Me</button>
        </div>
    }
})

function updateForm(className, errorMessage) {
    ReactDOM.render(
            React.createElement(Form, {
                className: className,
                errorMessage: errorMessage
            }),
            document.getElementById('container')
    )
}

var Form = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            showButton: false
        }
    },

    classNames: function () {
        return this.props.className
    },

    handleButtonClicked: function (event) {
        printMessage('Button Click handled')
        updateForm('success', '')
    },

    handleBlur: function (event) {
        printMessage('Input Blurred')
        updateForm('error', 'Why did the buttons onClick handler not ever run?')
    },

    showChild: function (event) {
        this.setState({
            showButton: true
        })
    },

    button: function () {
        if (this.state.showButton) {
            return <Button className="" handleClick={ this.handleButtonClicked }/>
        }
    },

    render: function () {
        printMessage('Parent Rendered')
        return <div>
            <div className={ this.classNames() }>
                <input onBlur={ this.handleBlur } onFocus={ this.showChild }/>
                <div className="error-message"> { this.props.errorMessage } </div>
                { this.button() } </div>
        </div>
    }
})

ReactDOM.render(
    <Form className="" errorMessage=""/>,
    document.getElementById('container')
)
```

And the CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#instructions,
#content {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

#messageCenter,
#container {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

#messageCenter div,
#container div {
  padding: 5px 0px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.error {
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.success {
  border: solid 1px green;
}

div.error-message {
  display: none;
}

.error div.error-message {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Is this a trick question? The button moves when the blur event is fired, because the error message moves it, so you never click it ?

Comment: No, this is not a trick question, this is a real bug we're having. You click the button before it moves. Clicking the button is what causes the input to blur.

Comment: @pyraz no, _focusing_ the button causes the input to blur. The `click` doesn't fire until the `mouseup` occurs on the button, which never happens because the button has moved.

Comment: It's unclear why you want `onMouseDown` and `onClick` on the same element in the first place.

Comment: FYI, having your UI jump around like that is a UX nightmare.

Comment: @Jack we registered both handlers to demonstrate that the `onMouseDown` event happens every time, whereas the `onClick` does not happen in the case where the error message is made visible.

Comment: And again, that's because the button moved when the mouse was pressed down, and the input lost focus, it will always do this, React or not.

Comment: Simplified example -> https://jsfiddle.net/sj43smxc/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `click` event is one `mousedown` followed by one `mouseup`, without leaving or changing the element.

If the element moves before the mouseup, or you put something over the button before the mouseup, or the mouse moves before the mouseup, or you manually reset `input.focus()` before the mouseup, or...

...anything else...

Then there's no click.

Comment: In this case it looks like they rerender the entire `Form` with their `handleBlur`, which would explain why the mouseup never occurs in this particular instance.

Comment: Actually @JesseKernaghan React is doing the right thing: the button itself hasn't changed, and thus React isn't replacing the element or its bindings. If you `mousedown` and hold the button down, wait for the layout to change, mouse ***back over the button*** and then `mouseup`, it appears to do what they expected it to do. So React plays a very small part here, compared to the layout change (if they were completely forcing React to rebuild a new immutable button, then yeah, that might be a problem).

Comment: I see! I had expected the button to be rerendered and lose the binding entirely because they fired `updateForm()`, which then fires `ReactDOM.render(` on the Form. I didn't realize that it would be a partial rerender either way. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Norguard I was under the understanding that React manages it's own event bus, and that event bus is tied to the element's in has reference to in the VirtualDom. Therefore, I would think that React would be able to handle the element moving, and still fire the original onClick handler. Is this not the case? For additional context, we found this issue by adding an inline validation to a form element, which included a message. Is there a better way to accomplish this behavior?

Comment: @pyraz Yes, it is. It manages its own virtual events, and virtual DOM, and renders/dispatches accordingly. However, that shouldn't even come into play here, because I believe it also only renders the nodes that have changed, in a similar fashion to how Redux reducers would have you shallow-copy unchanged nodes, as properties of "mutated" parents. As such, if that still holds true, the black-magic of the virtual-dom eventing and node reconciliation, et cetera, doesn't even need to come into play, I don't think.

Comment: @Norguard yeah, you're right, and when debugging this we even forced the child node to not re-render by change `shouldComponentUpdate` to return false, so it must no be re-rendering that node, and it's relying on the DOM element to get the `mousedown` and `mouseup`, which isn't happening. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The `onBlur` moves the button out from under the mouse pointer. That occurs before the click is handled and therefore you don't end up actually clicking on the button. This is fairly standard behaviour.